# How to specify a "Tomcat 6 Server Runtime" library in Maven 2?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, tomcat6

I'm working on a project with Eclipse 3.7, Tomcat 6 and Maven 2. The project has dependencies on jsp-api.jar and serlet-api.jar. But these two jars must be excluded from deploying to Tomcat 6, because they conflict with Tomcat 6's jars. So I need them at developing phase and don't need them at deploying phase. And I want to implement this requirement in an automatic way.
I have two solutions, but neither can satisfy my requirement:

1. Add dependencies in pom and exclude these 2 jars during deployment by adding

   ```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.3</version>
       <configuration>
         <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.4.jar,WEB-INF/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar</packagingExcludes>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
   ```

   maven-war-plugin prevents packing specified files during `mvn package` goal into war file. But when I use tomcat in Eclipse in development, I have to delete these 2 jars from tomcat working space manually every time when I republish the project.
2. Remove them from pom dependencies, add a tomcat 6 server run time library in Eclipse. In this case, developing is fine, but can't package with maven because two dependencies are missing in pom file.

How can I add a "Tomcat 6 server runtime library" in Maven so these 2 jars are not copied into project's lib directory and compiler can still find the dependencies?

Answer (score 6):

Just add the scope "provided" to the dependency.

Example:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```